# JVM -Xmn memory

Tags: java, memory, jvm

My jvm memory allocation scheme.

> -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -Xmn1536m

The official recommendation is that the young generation is 3/8 of the heap memory.

if the memory allocated by my -Xmn is small or large. What effect will it have?

Comment: What is a good size depends on your application, one application I had a new space of 24 G and a total size of 26 G.  The larger the new space, the less space there is for tenured space.

Comment: Having a larger eden space reduces the time between minor collections, but might make them longer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of the young generation will determine the time between minor GCs.  Objects are allocated in the Eden space using a simple pointer bumping approach, which is very fast (for multiple threads it is a bit more complicated by having thread local allocation blocks to eliminate the issue of contention).  The bigger your Eden space, the longer your application can create objects before the allocation pointer(s) reach the end of the address space.

When no more objects can be allocated in Eden space, a minor GC is performed that copies live objects from Eden to a survivor space and promotes objects that have reached the tenuring threshold to the old generation.  Most objects are very short-lived (the weak generational hypothesis) so, typically, only a small number of objects need to be copied.  Making your Eden space larger will also mean more objects have a chance to be dereferenced and you will end up placing a lower load on the old generation.

The 3/8 advice is good for a wide range of applications.  Obviously, for different applications, you may tune this up or down to fit the memory usage profile.  One important rule to follow though is to keep the young generation less than 50% of the heap space (i.e. the young generation should always be smaller than the old generation).  The reason for this is that, if not, the collector will run a major GC every time a minor GC is run.  This is because the collector needs to ensure there is enough space in the old gen to promote objects from the young gen.